# Name of painter from Chop/Seal (Characters identified: 曹維雲印)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I posted the other day but because it was my first time on the platform I didn't correctly upload the image. Here are the images and the question:
Can you let me know the name of the painter from his chop/seal?
Thank you!!!!!!!
Warm regards, Martin
[image: Seal of Painter]
[image: Painting]

Answer (score 1):

If you can identify the characters as "曹維雲印", then it literally means that this is the seal of a person named "曹維雲", which implies that the painter is called "曹維雲".